# Alter table add text to non-empty value

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table

Can someone give me an example of how I can alter a table value that has text inside already,
and keep that text but add new text in front of the existing text?
I'm trying to add additional text to 1600+ fields.

I was looking at MySQL and found reference to concatenate `CONCAT`, but as I understand, it adds text after a certain value.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add some extra text in one column in 1600+ rows? E.g. the column has the value "foo" and you want it to be "foo bar".

Comment: sorry you answered all to fast lol.i improoved my question.i want the new text be infront of the old text.not behind it

Comment: I hope you mean 1600 records and not fields. :)

Comment: If you just want text before you can use the example statement in my answer, but without the "'some text after'" part. Also make sure to include whitespaces - if needed, at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the value of a column use the UPDATE statement:

```
update myTable set myColumn = concat('some text before', myColumn, 'some text after') where <where condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add text where you want. Just concatenate them in the way you like.

```
select *,concat('your_text ',field) as new_text from table
```

or

```
select *,concat(field,' your_text') as new_text from table
```

It exists also concat_ws() function where ws means "with separator".

```
select *,concat_ws(' ','your_text',field) as new_text from table.
```

Once you're sure you've the right new content convert the select in an update query.
It's always a good practice trying the equivalent select before doing some mistake with update queries.

```
update table set field = concat('new text ',field)
where field is not null or field <> ""
```

Comment: Thank you Nick...you rulezz :)